# Bound of matrix

Tags: matrices

If all the entries of a matrix are continuous function of $x$ over a compact set. Could I make a statement that this matrix is bounded? Is there any theorems to support that?

Comment: Bounded in what topology/metric/norm?

Comment: @davidlowryduda I don't think topology helps, but yes, what metric/norm.

Comment: You can make exactly the same statements that you can make for a continuous function $f:\text{compact}\to\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @ davidlowryduda @ Don Thousand For example, A(x)  is what we considered. does it exist A(x') and A(x'')?  A(x') - A(x) > or = 0 for all x in compact set , A(x) - A(x'') > or = 0 for all x in compact set ? Here the >0 or = 0 means Nonnegative definite matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement that any entry of the matrix is a continuous function $K \to \mathbb{R}$ with $K$ compact says that the matrix determines a continuous function $A\colon K \to \mathbb{R}^{mn}$, where $n\times m$ is the dimension of the matrix.

As @Gae. S. says in the comments, we can conclude anything that one can conclude about a continuous function $f\colon K \to \mathbb{R}^{mn}$. The image of a compact space under a continuous map is compact, which says that $A(K)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$. Thus it is closed and bounded in the usual (Euclidean) topology on $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$. In particular, each coordinate lives within a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.